# A beginner ROR Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
<h1>All Articles</h1>

<ul>
   <% @articles.each.do |article| %>
  <li>
     <%= article.title %>
  </li>
 <% end %>
</ul>
```

I keep getting "syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting $end" I am totally confused on whats going on.

Comment: Replace the `.` between `each` and `do` with a space: `@articles.each do |article|`

Answer (score 1):

`do` is not a method of each: it's a signifier for the beginning of a block. You want this:

```
<h1>All Articles</h1>

<ul>
   <% @articles.each do |article| %>
  <li>
     <%= article.title %>
  </li>
 <% end %>
</ul>
```

Comment: @HannesNose good to hear. Welcome to StackOverflow. Please do not forget to upvote the answers you like and select the best answer by checking the mark.